# Tweepy Get List of Favorites for a Specific User

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am attempting to get a list of favorited tweets made by a specific user. Their twitter account indicates that they have favorited nearly 20k tweets but the list of favorites being returned through the API is only ~2,300 favorited tweets. Below is a sample of my python code:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
test_user = "someuser"

#print out each favorited tweet
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.favorites,id=test_user,wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
  count=200).pages(200):

  for status in page:
    print status.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8') + ": " 
      + status.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I assumed that the count = 200 and pages = 200 would give me 40,000 tweets max. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From a bit more digging on the twitter API, it looks like there is a cap on the number of tweets we can query. See [this question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-index-limits/49653) from the twitter developer forum.